# fix the showing gif in Java swing

Tags: java, swing, gif

I want to show a gif in java swing.

For show gif I use from these code but in both of them the gif is not moving and it like as an image is static.

first code:

```
void showGif() {
    try {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("address of gif");
        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(bufferedImage);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
        label.setVisible(true);
        panel.add(label);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

second code:

```
 void showGif() {
    try {
        ImageIcon imageIcon;
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("address of gif"));
        imageIcon = new ImageIcon(bufferedImage);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(imageIcon);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        label.setVisible(true);
        panel.add(label, TOP_ALIGNMENT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

please help me to show gif correctly.

Comment: Answer of that question have ImagePanel, but it not available in java 8

Comment: ImagePanel is a custom class presented as part of that question’s answer.  It is not a Java SE class in any version of Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `ImageIcon` in this case will be showing just the first frame of the GIF.

You can add the GIF to a JLabel, which you can add to the JPanel. Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource) out for further help.

Comment: how add GIF to JLable without ImageIcon and Icon?

Comment: @ali Why? Has it caused any problems?